# Changing all drawer navigator titles

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I got to the point where i need to translate my React-Native app in different languages. The thing is that when a new language is selected i need to translate the titles in the DrawerNavigator, basically translating the title from `navigationOptions`. How can i translate all the titles when i change the language, taking into consideration that i can not use the translate function in the `static navigationOptions`, this being a redux action. I have tried to pass the translate function as a navigation prop but that did not work. Any help?